# How to check date to/from with null value

Tags: javascript

1.Example: condition is valid

```
date_from = "2014-05-21 16:00:00";
date_now  = "2014-05-21 18:00:00";
date_to   = "2014-05-21 19:00:00";
```

2.Example: condition is valid

```
date_from = "2014-05-21 16:00:00";
date_now  = "2014-05-21 18:00:00";
date_to   = null;
```

3.Example: condition is valid

```
date_from = null;
date_now  = "2014-05-21 18:00:00";
date_to   = "2014-05-21 19:00:00";
```

4.Example: condition is not valid

```
date_from = "2014-05-21 16:00:00";
date_now  = "2014-05-21 18:00:00";
date_to   = "2014-05-21 17:00:00";
```

I have this condition:

```
if (data1.date_from <= voting_started && voting_started <= data1.date_to) {
//abc
}
```

It works well, if both date_from and date_to are not null, but if one is null, condition is not valid. How to check date with null value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalize it.

**Before** your `if` add this:

```
if(!date_to) {
    date_to = voting_started;
};
if(!date_from) {
    date_from = voting_started; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

or:

```
if ((data1.date_from === null || data1.date_from <= voting_started) &&
    (data1.date_to === null || voting_started <= data1.date_to)) {
//abc
}
```